# Get IndexPath of UITableView to change the color of a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, didselectrowatindexpath

I added a badge to the left of my `tableViewCell` as it is shown in [this example](http://myioslearning.blogspot.com/2016/09/how-to-make-circle-badge-on-left-of.html).
Then after getting that successfully done I moved to the next thing which is to add a swipe left/right on cell and show some options. I've successfully configured it by using [this library](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) on GitHub.
 
Now as I move forward I've added a cancel option on right swipe and user taps on it I want that badge (UIView) color to go Red.
I've added the green color to it as `appointmentCell.appointmentStatusIndicatorBadge.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;` So if I call this line again in `didTriggerLeftUtilityButtonWithIndex` it didn't pick the `appointmentStatusIndicatorBadge` because it was created in `PatientAppointmentTableViewCell` as `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *appointmentStatusIndicatorBadge;` and it's being used in `PatientViewController`

Here is the full method where I need to access it:

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerLeftUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
        {
            NSLog(@"Just Tapped Cancel");
//here I want to change the color to red
            [cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I tried to do it by making a new object of the class but that was a stupid thing to do. The issues is now I'm unable to track the `indexPath` as I'm no longer inside a delegate method of `TableView`. So How can I do that?

**EDIT**

Based on a comment here is the .h code of my tableViewCell. I'm not doing anything in .h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SWTableViewCell.h"

@interface PatientAppointmentTableViewCell : SWTableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *appointmentStatusIndicatorBadge;
@end
```

Comment: Can you show your Table Cell Class?

Comment: @Mr.UB see the edited version of my question.

Comment: Do you have a variable which can be used to store a flag to see if user has pressed the cancels?

Comment: @Mr.UB I know it when user press the cancel with this `didTriggerLeftUtilityButtonWithIndex` delegate method of `SWTableViewCell` class. I just want to know the indexPath on which it pressed cancel button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to get the indexPath of the cell:

```
NSLog(@"Just Tapped Cancel");
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Whereas, `cell` is the `cell` from following method:

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerLeftUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

method.